# Avoid repeating package description in DESCRIPTION file and roxygen package documentation

Tags: r, r-package

When making an R package, following the advice of https://r-pkgs.org/index.html, you seemingly need to put your package description in two separate places. Once, in the `Description` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file (described [here](https://r-pkgs.org/description.html)), and a second time in the package documentation that will be parsed by `roxygen2` (described [here](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#man-packages)). For the package documentation, I'm aware that this is useful for other things, such as `@import` statements, but you still need a `@description` section, and `devtools::check()` will complain if you do not.

However, this seems to me to be the same information: a short but multi-sentence description of your package. Is my understanding correct? If yes, is there a way to only write the description once, and copy it during the package build process? If not, what are the differences in the text that should be put in each location?